# Going to Pakistan in 3 weeks time but my NICOP is expired and my son's hasn't arrived yet

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, pakistani-citizens, pakistan

My NICOP is expired and I have already booked a flight to Pakistan via Qatar Airways.

My wife has a valid NICOP card but my 5 years old child  has never had a NICOP or any other Pakistani ID card other than the British passport.

I have made an appointment for next Monday to renew my NICOP and apply for my child's new NICOP card.

My question is, what if the cards of my child and mine don't arrive in time, can we still travel to Pakistan, given that we have the receipts as a proof of application?

Comment: Can't you get Pakistani passports?

Answer (score 5):

Went to the Pakistan embassy and applied for a NICOP card. It took about 30 minutes and the people there were extremely helpful.

I applied for the executive one and they told me it would get to me in 14 working days.

Applied on 21st January and the card was here on 27th.

Very quick & hassle free service.

Thanks once again for your help

Answer (score 2):

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with an expired Pakistan
>   Origin Card (POC) or an **expired National ID Card for Overseas Pakistanis (NICOP)** can obtain a 72 hours landing permit on arrival.

So with a valid British passport and expired NICOP, you can get admitted for 72 hours. How to extend that, I don't know, but I can't imagine it not being possible (ask at passport control)

As for your child, they **will** need a NICOP, or else a visa.

Comment: Many thanks Crazydre. Just wondering if let's say we apply for my child's card and it doesn't arrive till the day we fly out, will they allow us to fly?

Comment: @ZSharif Ask the embassy if they can give a "visa exempt" stamp in your child's British passport. If not, no, you can't fly without a NICOP (valid or expired) or visa

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Will ask them on Monday

Comment: man, you should have posted link to the website rather copying the text from there.